# Different datetime format returns wrong result set in EF Core and LINQ. DateTime.ParseExact does not work

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.2, ef-core-2.1

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application with the culture set to `en-GB` using a date time format of `dd/mm/yyyy`.

I am using:

- .NET Core 2.1
- EF Core 2.2
- SQL Server 2019 (v15)
- The date column is of type `datetime2`

However for one of my queries I need the date to be of format `yyyy-mm-dd` when querying through EF Core.

```
var xyx = db.zyz
            .Where(x => x.date >= startdate && x.date<= enddate)
            ......
```

The above query fails to return the result set even if there is a record in table zyz in accordance to the condition.

This I think is happening only when startdate and enddate are the same.

E.g. let's say zyz has a record for date `2020-04-19`

Query

```
   var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20200419","yyyyMMdd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var xyx = db.zyz
                .Where(x=>x.date >= dt && x.date<= dt)
                ......
```

This fails to fetch any rows. It returns 0 rows.

I think this is because of the date time format.

The date field in zyz in the db is of the format `2020-19-04 00:00:00.0000000`

Two questions come to mind:

- Is this because of the datetime format that I am not getting a result? Does EF Core not take care of the formatting?
- When I use `ParseExact` and different means to parse the date to a format I want. It does not work. I always get the date in the format of `dd/mm/yyyy`.

What I have tried, to parse the date:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20200415","yyyyMMdd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime theTime = DateTime.ParseExact("20200415",
                                        "yyyyMMdd",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                        DateTimeStyles.None);

var dts = DateTime.ParseExact("20200415", "yyyyMMdd",new CultureInfo("en-ZA"));
```

The above queries always return date of format `19/04/2020 00:00:00`

As I understand since datetime is just a datatype, shouldn't the query be independent of the datetime format and return data irrespective of the datetime format?

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact("2020-04-19","yyyyMMdd"` - I'd expect that to fail to start with, given that the pattern doesn't match the data. I would strongly encourage you to separate out "parsing in .NET" from "how the query behaves". Construct a `DateTime` value just with `new DateTime(...)` and use that in your query. If that behaves as you expect it to, then the problem is presumably in the purely-.NET part, so you can remove the EF part from the equation.

Comment: `x.date >= mydate && x.date<= mydate` will evaluate to `true` only when `x.date == mydate`

Comment: x.date >= dt && x.date <= dt.
How do you expect 2019-12-06 01:52:10.0000000>= 2020-04-19 && 2019-12-06 01:52:10.0000000 <= 2020-04-19 ??

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry that was a typo,have edited. Even with the same format .i.e `DateTime.ParseExact("20200419","yyyyMMdd"` I always get a date of format 19-04-2020 and not 20200419 as I expect.

Comment: @IvanStoev yup in my case this is true. I have a record where date = mydate. But it still returns no result set.

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti that date is just an example of the format. :) Will edit the example

Comment: A `DateTime` value does not have a format, and you shouldn't expect it to. If you write `int x = 0x10; Console.WriteLine(x);` do you expect that to print "0x10"? No, it just prints "16" because that's the value, however it was arrived at. As I said before, you really need to do some more diagnostic work to find out whether the problem is in how you come up with your `DateTime` values, or what EF is doing.

Comment: @JonSkeet so any format the date is in the table,  ef core should give me the result if it has one. .i.e if I have a record in the table with date col` 2020-15-04`, and in the query I use date showing -> `15-04-2020`, ef core should return a result. Am I right in my understnading ? :)

Comment: @Abhilash Gopalakrishna you said that fails to fetch any rows, of course with that condition, searches only dates that are equals.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "so any format the date is in the table". But you haven't told us what your database schema looks like, which doesn't help - if you've got appropriate data types in your schema, then again, that data doesn't really have a format - I'd expect to see it formatted differently depending on the connection settings in SQL Studio or whatever.

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti I have a date which is equal in the records. I changed the query a little for easier understanding, let me put it back as it is . to avoid confusions :)

Comment: 2020-19-04 01:52:10.0000000 is not equal, 2020-19-04 01:52:10.0000000 is bigger than 2020-04-19. 1:52 past to midnight :)

Comment: @JonSkeet the date time column is of type `datetime2`. When I say 'any format'. What I mean is. How the date is represented in the table or the query is insgnificant ..i.e in the table when I see the date it is seen as as `2020-04-19` and in the query it is seen as `19-04-2020`. I think this change is only bcoz of the server locale setting/the application locale and does not affect how the query interprets the date. This is the perspective I am looking at it from :)

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti my query was wrong, I was sending `2020-05-19 00:00:00` for both whereas I had to send `2020-05-19 11:59:00`

thank you :)

Comment: @JonSkeet the query was wrong and now that it is working, it shows makes it clear how datetime does not have a format . thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys the query itself was wrong.

**What was wrong :**

In case of same start date and end date :

```
var xyx = db.zyz
            .Where(x => x.date >= startdate && x.date<= enddate)
            ......
```

**I was sending:**

2020-04-19 00:00:00 for both

**I had to send:**

`2020-04-19 00:00:00` - for start date
`2020-04-19 11:59:00` -  for end date

As pointed out by **Ivan Stoev** and  **Stefano Balzarotti** in the comments.

Wrote this answer as it makes it clear that datetime is a type and does not have a format as pointed out by **Jon Skeet** in the comments.